# Curl ftp error Could not resolve host

Tags: ftp, curl

I am trying to connect to a partner site from Ubuntu server via ftp using curl. The command is given by the business partner

```
curl -v -kG --ftp-method nocwd --ftp-ssl -cert "domainname.crt" --key "domainname.key" -u user:password ftp://ftp.partner.biz/
```

I get following error.

```
* Could not resolve host: domainname.crt
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: domainname.crt
*   Trying <ipaddr>:21...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ftp.partner.biz (<ipaddr>) port 21 (#1)
< 220 (<partnername>)
> AUTH SSL
< 504 unknown security mechanism
> AUTH TLS
< 234 AUTH TLS OK starting TLS negotiation
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 1
```

I see port 22 and 443 listening on my server

```
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1570/sshd: /usr/sbi
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      5802/apache2
```

The partner says there is no error log on their side. Is it something to do with tcp6 or something else. I cannot change the command format since the partner says it works with their other customers. I am helpless.
Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` is complaining that it cannot reach "domainname.crt" because it does not know the ip address of this hostname by yielding the following message mentioned in your question.

```
* Could not resolve host: domainname.crt
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: domainname.crt
```

Assumably you do not intend to connect to some site named "domainname.crt"; it is most likely the name of your certificate file stored somewhere on your client machine. Please double-check your `curl` command. Instead of your original command, it should be

```
curl -v -kG --ftp-method nocwd --ftp-ssl --cert "domainname.crt" --key "domainname.key" -u user:password ftp://ftp.partner.biz/
```

I guess you missed a hyphen in `--cert` argument.

Comment: Yes domainname.crt points to cert file local on my server. It worked. The mistake was cert had only one hyphen. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You have small mistake in the command. The text:

```
-cert "domainname.crt"
```

must be

```
--cert "domainname.crt"
```